# how to go to previously viewed tab on safari

Tags: safari

There is a common shortcut of going to previously viewed browser tab (on Vimum, Termux etc). So for example on [Chrome Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium) this is how it's defined:

> ^ visit the previously-visited tab

Is there such a shortcut on safari?

note: This shortcut doesn't exist on the [Vimium version of Safari](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vimari/id1480933944?mt=12)

Comment: How do you define „previous tab“? The one to the left, the one shown before, something else?

Comment: Literally the last tab viewed.. doesn't matter if it's immediately to the left or to the right. For example you can be on tab 1 then jump to tab 10, in this case last tab viewed ks tab 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also found out that there is no such a shortcut for going back to the previous tab in Safari, and wrote an extension for that. If you still need that functionality, you can check the extension out on the [App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/tabback/id1660506599).

Also, there is another [extension](https://apps.apple.com/app/last-tab-for-safari/id1462804843?l=en&mt=12), which has a different shortcut, from another author.

Comment: wow this is great! I bought it and it works perfect. However I wish you would give the user the ability to customize their own keyboard shortcut. Currently you only offer Ctrl 1/2/3/A/Z, I would like to chose my own

Comment: Thanks! I would love to give the users that extra option, but it is just not possible in Safari, unlike in Chrome. I mean technically it can be done, but in that way, an extension will require permission to read webpage contents and browsing history. But if I ever write one with that option, I'll contact you here :)

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, how were you able to manipulate safari? was this done using Automator or something? I'm a big sucker for doing anything that can make my work more productive in Mac

Comment: There are a bunch of web browser APIs available, and I used them. If you'd like to build your own Safari extension, you can check out things like [Building a Safari app extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension) and [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions). Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @abbood, I’m happy to let you know that I worked on another way to implement support for a custom shortcut and just released a new version! You can update the app to the latest version on the App Store :D

Comment: Hi yes I just got your update, it's _amazing_ thanks so much!

Comment: Hi a quick comment: on your extension, whenever the user has created a custom extension, make sure to display it prominently. Sometimes the user forgets what the extension is! Ie right now I must pretend that I want to set a custom extension again only to find out wha the original extension is lol

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Hi there, I think your latest change broke it :( It no longer works (I tested by both using Ctrl+A and a custom key as well) Please fix my life depends on this plugin lol

Comment: Hi, I think I found the cause of the problem. The app will probably work again after selecting 'default' or 'custom' shortcut in Safari toolbar TabBack menu, and this won't happen again in the future updates. I'm sorry for the bug introduced! If you need further support, you can also contact me via contact.seungwoochoe@gmail.com for faster feedback.

Comment: ok cool I simply deleted the plugin and reinstalled and it was fine!

Comment: Thanks so much for this extension!

Answer (score 2):

On Safari, you can shift between tabs on a widow using the following key commands:

- ⌃⇥ (ctrl-tab) moves to the next tab
- ⌃⇧⇥ (ctrl-shift-tab) moves to the previous tab

There is no specific key-command for moving to the last-viewed tab, but under the History menu you can access the last-viewed tab or reopen the last closed tab. There's a shortcut for the latter (⇧⌘T).

Comment: Thanks Ted. I'm aware of the shortcuts you mentioned. The idea of "a last visited tab" is to not have to worry about the placement of tabs. For example if you have 10 tabs (t1, t2, .. , t10), and you want to jump between t3 and t7, you don't have to cycle through several tabs, it would be a single keyboard shortcut